# WSGI can't find imports within same directory

Tags: python, apache, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy a Flask server with Apache and WSGI but I am getting a 500 error when loading the homepage of my application. Flask and Apache itself seem to be connected fine however when I look in my Apache logs I am getting the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keys'` with `keys.py` being a file in the same directory as my `__init__.py` flask file.

My `.conf` file in Apache's available-sites is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName SERVER'S IP
                ServerAdmin email@email.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/FlaskApp-error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/FlaskApp-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My .wsgi file is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
```

My directory structure is the following:

[image: The directory structure of my FlaskApp folder]
How can I get the `__init__.py` file to see the other Python files in the same directory?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using absolute or relative imports?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, if I do `from myproject.keys import api_key`, then I can get the import to work. The full path for my project is `/var/www/FlaskApp/myproject`. I think it has something to do with the `sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")` line in my .wsgi file? While it does work, I'd prefer not to have to change this for the production/server code anytime I pull from my git repo and it isn't pretty, either.

Answer (score 0):

In your wsgi.py file, change :

```
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")
```

by :

```
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/myproject")
```